# Data frames and datetimes

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a dataset that I’m working with and I’m trying to change the format of my time column. The current format reads like this, example: “2022-05-23 23:06:58”, I’m trying to change this to only show me the hour times and erase the dates.

Other info: I want to make this change within my data frame, not just random times. I want to change over 100,000 rows so I need a function or solution that will do so. Tidyverse, Lubridate, Format, etc. Thank you guys.

Edit: There was one thing I may not have articulated fully, I wanted to keep the exact time and nothing else. so ‘23:48:07 would’ be how I’m looking for it not just the our. I need it so I can eventually subtract the time passed between two columns. You get me?

Answer (score 2):

Try this
for the first question here is the code to convert to the hour of the day

```
your_time<-format(as.POSIXct(your_time), format = "%H:%M:%S")


#which gives "23" hours of the day
```

Since you want to apply on a large dataset we use this below

```
large_df%>%
  mutate(Hour = format(as.POSIXct(Datetime), format ="%H:%M:%S"))
```

where the large_df is your large dataset worth over 100,000 records
The mutate will open another column for the result which is named the Hour column
and the Datetime is the DateTime column in your large_df dataset

Comment: Thank you so much. There was one thing I may not have articulated fully, I wanted to keep the exact time and nothing else. so ‘23:48:07 would’ be how I’m looking for it not just the our. I need it so I can eventually subtract the time passed between two columns. You get me?

Comment: Ok
If that's what you want, you need to change the format from "%H" to this format
"%H:%M:%S"
see the script edited

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you. I’m gonna follow you cause I’m just getting started with R and you seem like a good person to ask.

Comment: You're always welcome.
don't forget to upvote my answer as it has helped you solve your problem.

Comment: It says I need a reputation of at least 15, this was my first interaction so I can’t yet but I won’t forget about you! 
I have one more question how ever. I have column in my dataset: “Rider_type” and the answer for each rider is either member or non member. How do create two separate columns so the members and non members are in separate columns?

Comment: could you share a sample of your question .....its always good to share a sample and the end result for guidance

Comment: Code
     B
     A….  Say there’s a pattern of this. Each row for this column would either be A or B. I want to create to separate columns so my B results are in one column & my A results are in another. I’m typing on a phone so it may not have formatted how a want. Say row 1A is the column name: “Code”. Row 2A is: “A”, Row 3A is “B”. And the subsequent rows have similar answers. I want to separate them. I Hope that makes sense.

Comment: what exactly do you want to separate

Comment: I want it some the users or rows whose answers are “A” to be in one column. & the users or rows with answers “B” to be in a separate column. They’re in one column now, I want them in two separate columns.

Comment: Try and ask the question in another thread, not this thread since the initial question has been answered.

you can tag me with the new question.

Comment: I think I tagged you, if not, here’s the link to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/72803017/19303355

Answer (score 0):

Is the time as a string ok? Cause then you can use `substr` to extract the hour and minutes like so:

```
time <- c("2022-05-23 23:02:58", "2022-05-23 13:52:58", "2022-05-23 03:31:58", "2022-05-23 09:09:58")
n <- nchar(time)
hour <- substr(time, n - 7, n - 3)
```

Just `time` with your 100.000 row time column

Comment: Hi, I can’t use it as a string because I’m converted two different columns in to the hour “23:04:51” format in order to subtract them to find time passed, so I can’t use strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
hour("2022-05-23 23:06:58") # 23
```